# Flawed Understanding of Futures in For Comprehension

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Most likely I'm not using the `For` comprehension appropriately but my question is relatively generic I think. I have two `Futures` created inside a Play Action.

1. The first calls my cache to get a value
2. The second then calls a web service (there is no dependency on the value from cache however)

Even though I could instantiate these `Future`s outside the `for` to give them the opportunity to run in parallel, I want them in sequence because **I only want the 2nd `Future` (web service call) to be created if the `value` was found in the cache.**

```
for {
        value <- getValueFromCache   // Future[Option[String]]

        wsResponse <- callWebService(value)   // Future[WSResponse]

 } yield wsResponse
```

**My Problem**
**When I execute the above, and the `value` is Not found in the cache, the second Future (the web service call) is still created/executed - which I do Not want.**

My understanding of the `for` comprehension is that even if the second task is not directly dependant on the first, the second will only run if the first completed successfully.

If the `value` is not found in the cache, `value = None`.
Is this why the 2nd `Future` still gets created/executed - because `None` is still considered a successful completion of the first `Future`?

Under what circumstances will the 2nd `Future` not get created - if, and only if, the first `Future` completes with a `Exception`?

I was considering using an `if 1st not complete properly then do not continue` type of statement but this still leaves my understanding of how `for` works with a big gap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this why the 2nd Future still gets created/executed - because None is still considered a successful completion of the first Future?

Yes, you end up with a `Future` that completed successfully but contains `None`, which is completely valid.

I don't know what the signature for `callWebService` is, but if you want to stop on `None`, you can `filter` the `Future`, which will cause it to fail, and subsequent lines in the for-comprehension will not execute. Or you could also try to match out the value from the `Option`, which would also cause the `Future` to fail on `None`.

```
for {
    value <- getValueFromCache.filter(_.nonEmpty)
    wsResponse <- callWebService(value) // requires `callWebService` to accept an Option
} yield wsResponse
```

Or

```
for {
    Some(value) <- getValueFromCache
    wsResponse <- callWebService(value) // requires `callWebService` to accept the type contained in the `Option`
} yield wsResponse
```

Or even

```
for {
    value <- getValueFromCache.map(_.get)
    wsResponse <- callWebService(value)
} yield wsResponse
```

Comment: m-z, you're a f**ing genius - pardon my french. Thanks.